# Is there a rectangular tiling based on the Padovan sequence?

Tags: soft-question, sequences-and-series, recurrences, tiling

I'm thinking of developing a rectangular tiling based on the Padovan sequence (think of the Fibonacci mosaic). It seems like something that should exist, but I can't find anything in the literature. Do you know of something like this and where I can find it?

Comment: I can't think of "the Fibonacci mosaic" since I've never heard of it. Reference? Link?

Comment: "Padovan tiling" turns up on top of page 7 of https://people.csail.mit.edu/ddeford/DeFord_Enumerating_Distinct.pdf but with no illustration.

Comment: @GerryMyerson See the two top tilings here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number. I'm using the term mosaic because different size tiles are used. And thanks for the link, but it's not quite what I'm after.

Comment: OK. You wouldn't take a tiling with equilateral triangles, would you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence

Comment: No. That one is very well known. I've done that one and the plastic pentagon gnomon as well.

Comment: I think your question is quite vague. It is not hard to build a sequence of plane filling rectangles in which some side lengths or areas resemble the Padovan sequence, but it is absolutely not clear whether these would satisfy you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please define rectangular tiling?

The Fibonacci numbers count number of ways to tile a $1\times n$-strip with rectangles of size $1 \times 1$ and $1\times 2$.
This is easy to see from the recurrence.

Now, the Padovan sequence count number of ways to tile a $1\times n$ rectangle with rectangles of size $1\times 2$ and $1\times 3$.
One needs to be a bit careful with initial conditions, so that there is one way to tile the $1\times 1$-rectangle.

Comment: By rectangular tiling I mean a whorled figure where the tiles circle around and increase in size according to some sequence or numbers raised to successive powers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number for an example with the Fibonacci sequence. Of course, the Padovan sequence would require rectangles rather than squares.

Comment: @CyeWaldman Which figure do you mean?  (There are 10.)  "Rectangular tiling" suggests the third one whose caption begins "Thirteen $(F_7)$ ways" showing tilings of a $1 \times 6$ board with $1\times1$ and $1\times 2$ tiles, in which case Per's answer seems appropriate.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Thanks for looking. I'm talking about the first and second figures on that web page. The point being to create a tessellated figure using only the integers in the sequence.

Comment: @CyeWaldman So you want a tiling of the plane using rectangles whose side lengths are sequential Padovan numbers, hopefully in some sort of spiral.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Well, that's exactly what I'm talking about and I've developed it already. I'm merely trying to find out if it's been done before. I didn't want to go posting it anywhere without verifying that it hasn't been done before. I apologize if I've caused any misrepresentations.